# calling a package from shell script

Tags: oracle, unix, plsql, oracle12c

I have a package create with multiple procedure defined. I am trying to call this package from shell script.
My package is written under schema ADM.
Package name is: PK_COMPUTE_FIELDS.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE ADM.PK_COMPUTE_FIELDS AS
PROCEDURE computeBalTotal(p_prd_id in integer,p_seg_id IN integer);
  PROCEDURE computeBilAmt(p_prd_id in integer,p_seg_id IN integer);
  PROCEDURE computePaidAmt(p_prd_id in integer,p_seg_id IN integer);
  END PK_COMPUTE_FIELDS ;
CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE BODY ADM.PK_COMPUTE_FIELDS 
AS
PROCEDURE computeBalTotal(p_prd_id in integer,p_seg_id IN integer) IS
BEGIN
//derivation logic
END;
  PROCEDURE computeBilAmt(p_prd_id in integer,p_seg_id IN integer)  IS
BEGIN
//derivation logic
END;

  PROCEDURE computePaidAmt(p_prd_id in integer,p_seg_id IN integer)  IS
BEGIN
//derivation logic
END;

END PK_COMPUTE_FIELDS ;
```

I am using the below shell script to call this package

```
sqlplus -s <USER>/<PWD>@<DBNAME> <<EOF >> $LOG_NAME

set serveroutput on
whenever sqlerror exit failure rollback
DECLARE 
  P_PRD_ID NUMBER;
  P_SEG_ID NUMBER;

BEGIN 
  P_PRD_ID := 1907;
  P_SEG_ID := 1;

 execute immediate ADM.PK_COMPUTE_FIELDS.computeBalTotal( P_PRD_ID, P_SEG_ID );
  COMMIT; 
END; 

/
EOF
```

I am getting an error as:

```
ERROR at line 9:
ORA-06550: line 9, column 20:
PLS-00201: identifier 'ADM.PK_COMPUTE_FIELDS.computeBalTotal' must be declared
ORA-06550: line 9, column 2:
PL/SQL: Statement ignored
```

Please guide me to correct this issue.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need `execute immediate` to call the procedure since you already have a `BEGIN..END` block.

change it to simple

```
ADM.PK_COMPUTE_FIELDS.computeBalTotal( P_PRD_ID, P_SEG_ID );
```

Procedures with known arguments can be called directly inside PL/SQL like the above.
`EXECUTE IMMEDIATE` is used in a procedure to execute a dynamic SQL statement(`select,insert,update,delete` etc) or anonymous PL/SQL block (those which use `BEGIN..END`;). It is only required when you have arguments: table names,column names etc that you don't know in advance.

If you want to call a procedure outside  a `BEGIN..END` (SQL* plus scope ),
you may use `EXECUTE`

`EXECUTE schema.pkg_name.proc_name(args)` or simply `EXEC schema.pkg_name.proc_name(args)`

Comment: when I do without execute immediate, it is saying identifier must be declared. just trying to know how can I do that?   ORA-06550: line 9, column 2:
PLS-00201: identifier 'ADM.PK_COMPUTE_FIELDS' must be declared
ORA-06550: line 9, column 2:
PL/SQL: Statement ignored